# Does ie read stylesheets outside of conditional comments?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, stylesheet, conditional-comments

I've been doing a bit of reading around this subject, and I can't seem to find an answer that specifically answers this question.

Using this code as an example:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-style.css" />
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

Would IE6 open and run `it-style.css` **and** `style.css`, and if not, why not? Also, does the order in which you place conditional and non-conditional stylesheets matter?

Comment: Of course it does! we usually put style.css above that conditional style, then in the conditional style file put the IE hackes etc to make the page readable in IE too

Comment: So by way of an example, if I have the line `p{ color:red; }` in `style.css` (placed above all other conditional stylesheets), and then the line `p{ color:blue; }` in `ie-style.css` (placed below `style.css`), ie6 would read them in that order, and only use the latter. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will open both.

Whatever style sheet is placed last has higher priority.

If this attribute was in `ie-style.css`

```
body {
    background:#000000; //black
}
```

and this attribute was in `style.css`

```
body {
    background:#FF0000; //red
}
```

and this is what the order of style sheets were in your `<head>`

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-style.css" />
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

then the body will be `red` even if you were on IE.